# Scoring and grading answers against an answer key

Tags: performance, beginner, c, homework

This is for a university assignment (don't worry the code is in working order), and while I could hand it in as-is and receive full marks I feel like there is probably a more efficient and better way to handle what I am doing.

**What the code does**

Takes user input of 4 names and for each name take True / False assignment scores in the format of 0 for False and 1 for True; then compare against the user input answer key and give: highest score, number correct for each name, and the letter grade which is based upon the highest score of the 4 names (more about that in the comments of the `computeGrade()` function)

**Sample Input**

> ```
> Information for Student #1
> Name: Smith
> Answers: 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
>
> Information for Student #2
> Name: Tony
> Answers: 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
>
> Information for Student #3
> Name: Patty
> Answers: 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
>
> Information for Student #4
> Name: Meg
> Answers: 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
>
> Please enter the Answer Key: 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
> ```

**Sample Output**

> ```
> Name      Answers                                      Number Correct      Grade
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Smith     0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1      19                  A
> Tony      0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1      9                   F
> Patty     1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1      8                   F
> Meg       1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0      15                  B
>
>
> Answer Key                                             Highest Score
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0                19
> ```

**Concerned parts**

Ultimately, I dislike the amount of `for` loops I'm using, especially in the `void computeGrade()` and `void printAll()` functions, that and I'm not sure if I'm just being OCD or if there's a better way to handle it. Also, I know my `printf` formatting probably isn't the best and I'm not as concerned with it as the rest of the program (but still slightly concerned). An overall review would be nice though as I come from being a beginner in Java to a beginner in C.

**Side Notes:**

- I'm required to split the program up into the 4 functions you see in the code.
- This may or may not annoy some of you, but the reason I've declared all my variables used in the `for` loops outside is because my university's compiler uses something before C99 and of course won't allow `for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)`. (It was real bummer having it work in Visual Studio 2015 then have to fix it just to turn the assignment in.)

---

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // Required for Visual Studio 2015
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_STUDENTS 4 // Defining the number of students / For use in our arrays
#define NAMES_LENGTH 20 // Defining the maximum length of the names of the students / For use in our arrays
#define NUM_ANSWERS 20 // Defining the number of answers to be marked / For use in our arrays

void initialize(); // Initialize applicable arrays / Function prototype for Module 1000
void readData(); // Read in data / Function prototype for Module 2000
void computeGrade(); // Compute Grades / Function prototype for Module 3000
void printAll(); // Print all data / Function prototype for Module 4000

char sNames[NUM_STUDENTS][NAMES_LENGTH]; // Global Array for storing the names of the students
char sGrades[NUM_STUDENTS][1]; // Global Array for storing the grades of the students

int aKey[NUM_ANSWERS]; // Global Array for storing the answer key
int aCorrect[NUM_STUDENTS]; // Global Array for storing number of answers correct for the students
int sAnswers[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_ANSWERS]; // Global Array for storing the answers of the students
int aHighest; // Global Variable to store the highest score

/* MODULE 0000 */

int main(void) {

    initialize(); // Call the initialize function to initialize aCorrect array to 0
    readData(); // Call the readData function to take user input
    computeGrade(); // Call the computeGrade function to calculate the grades of the students
    printAll(); // Call the printAll function to print all resulting data

    return 0;
}

/* MODULE 1000 */

void initialize() {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        aCorrect[i] = 0;
    }

}

/* MODULE 2000 */

void readData() {

    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        printf("Information for Student #%d\n", (i + 1)); // Label which student is being marked

        printf("Name: ", (i + 1)); // Prompt for the students name
        scanf("%s", sNames[i]); // Scan in the students name 

        printf("Answers: "); // Prompt for the answers

        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &sAnswers[i][j]); // Scan in the students answers
        }

        printf("\n");

    }

    printf("Please enter the Answer Key: ");

    int k;

    for (k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
        scanf("%d", &aKey[k]); // Scan in the answer key
    }

}

/* MODULE 3000 */

void computeGrade() {

    /* Compute the number of answers correct */

    int k, l;

    for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < 20; l++) {
            if (sAnswers[k][l] == aKey[l]) { // Compare students answer to the answer key
                aCorrect[k]++; // If correct answer, add to the array which stores the number of correct answers for that student
            }
        }
    }

    /* Find the highest score */

    int m;

    for (m = 0; m < 4; m++) {
        if (aCorrect[m] > aHighest) // Compare the students number of answers correct for each student to the current highest
            aHighest = aCorrect[m]; // If higher than the current, replace with the new highest
    }

    /* Compute the grade */

    int p;

    for (p = 0; p < 4; p++) {
            if (aCorrect[p] >= (aHighest - 3)) { // Compare the students number of answers correct to the current highest minus 3 (requirement for an A)
                sGrades[p][1] = 'A'; // Store the grade A into the array holding student grades
            }
            else if (aCorrect[p] >= (aHighest - 5)) { // Compare the students number of answers correct to the current highest minus 5 (requirement for a B)
                sGrades[p][1] = 'B'; // Store the grade B into the array holding student grades
            }
            else if (aCorrect[p] >= (aHighest - 7)) { // Compare the students number of answers correct to the current highest minus 7 (requirement for a C)
                sGrades[p][1] = 'C'; // Store the grade C into the array holding student grades
            }
            else if (aCorrect[p] >= (aHighest - 9)) { // Compare the students number of answers correct to the current highest minus 9 (requirement for a D)
                sGrades[p][1] = 'D'; // Store the grade D into the array holding student grades
            }
            else //  The students number of answers correct is below the current highest minus 9 (requirement for a F)
            sGrades[p][1] = 'F'; // Store the grade F into the array holding student grades
    }

}

/* MODULE 4000 */

void printAll() {

    // C = Column
    // R = Row

    /* Print Labels */
    printf("\n\n%-*s", 10, "Name"); // C1 R1
    printf("%-*s", 45, "Answers"); // C2 R1
    printf("%-*s", 20, "Number Correct"); // C3 R1
    printf("%-*s\n", 10, "Grade"); // C4 R1

    /* Print a dashed line */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 80; i++) 
        printf("%c", '-'); // C1 R2

    printf("\n");

    /* Print data */
    int j, k;
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) { // For loop to print data on all 4 students
        printf("%-*s", 10, sNames[j]); // C1 - R3, R4, R5, R6
        for (k = 0; k < 19; k++)  // For loop again to print the students answers
            printf("%d ", sAnswers[j][k]);
        printf("%-*d", 7, sAnswers[j][19]); // C2 - R3, R4, R5, R6
        printf("%-*d", 20, aCorrect[j]); // C3 - R3, R4, R5, R6
        printf("%-*c\n", 10, sGrades[j][1]); // C4 - R3, R4, R5, R6
    }

    /* Print Labels */
    printf("\n\n%-*s", 10, "Answer Key"); // C1 R7
    printf("%-*s", 45, ""); // C2 R7
    printf("%s\n", "Highest Score"); // C3 R7

    /* Print a dashed line */
    int l;
    for (l = 0; l < 68; l++)
        printf("%c", '-'); // C1 R8

    printf("\n");

    /* Print Data */
    int m;
    for (m = 0; m < 20; m++) // For loop to print the answer key
        printf("%d ", aKey[m]);

    printf("%-*s", 15, ""); // C3 R9
    printf("%-*d\n\n", 20, aHighest); // C3 R9

}
```

Comment: Not teaching C99 in 2015 is really sad.

Comment: This would make a good codegolf challenge

Comment: @SztupY You think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Lint

Some of the more obvious simple things that the compiler didn't complain about:

- Why are you hard-coding `4` and `20` all over the place?
- It's conventional to order the functions (i.e. `main()` at the bottom) such that you don't need forward declarations.
- Commenting every line is very distracting, and more harmful than helpful.  A lot of the code (e.g. `printf()` and `scanf()`) is obvious, and you're making me read everything twice.  Note that `//` comments were introduced in C99, so your code is neither C89-compliant, nor is it using C99 features, which puts it in a grey zone.

  Your `/* */` comments, on the other hand, are somewhat helpful. Keep those.

  More importantly, instead of the meaningless `/* Module 1000 */` comments, tell us what global variables the function uses. Documenting those dependencies and side-effects is crucial.

### Data structures

First of all, I'm glad to see that you broke down the work into four helper functions.  It would be even better if you passed parameters instead of using global variables.  Passing arrays in C is somewhat tricky, though, so I wouldn't fault a beginner for avoiding that hurdle.

Have you learned about `struct`s yet?  If so, I would prefer to see an array of four `struct student_record`s than to have the information dispersed into various four-element arrays.

As noted in the compiler warnings, `sGrades[n][1]` involves out-of-bounds access.  You don't need a `char[][1]` if all you need to store is one byte — just a one-dimensional `char[]` will do.

You don't need `initialize()`.  You can just use an [initializer](//stackoverflow.com/q/201101/1157100).  In fact, [global variables are automatically initialized to zero](//stackoverflow.com/q/2091499/1157100).  (Better to be safe than sorry, though!)

### Input / output

`scanf()` is a tricky function to use correctly.  In particular, this line

> ```
> scanf("%s", sNames[i]); // Scan in the students name
> ```

is problematic.  Things that could go wrong:

- Buffer overflow if the input exceeds 19 bytes.
- The whole program malfunctions if the user enters a first name and a last name.
- You didn't check for end-of-file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows), which would lead to `sNames[i]` not being written to at all.

In that situation, to read a line of text up to a certain length limit, I suggest using `fgets()` instead.

Printing could be better as well.  For example, for `/* Print Labels */`, I suggest

```
printf("%-10s%-45s%-20s%-10s\n", "Name", "Answers", "Number Correct", "Grade");
```

`printf("%c", '-');` is overkill; `putchar('-')` will do.

Please do not omit "optional" braces like that in your for-loops — you *will* someday contribute to a coding accident, perhaps a costly one.  Just put the braces in, or, if you *really* feel the urge, write [one-liner](//programmers.stackexchange.com/a/16530/51698) blocks.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I actually have to use function prototypes to get full marks which is why I'm doing it but I didn't know it was conventional to put main at the bottom. I haven't learned about struct's yet but I will see what I can do with those instead. It's good to know I don't need initialize() also, but again I was forced to do it. Thanks for all the input.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention the reason there are so many comments is because this particular assignment requires "full internal documentation". It's stupid but if I don't I won't get full credit. Trust me I won't be so dang annoying the next time around (and every other time). :P

Comment: If your instructor specifically requires line-by-line comments, Code Review members will give him/her an earful of complaints. As I said, your `/* comments */` are helpful, and should be sufficient. The `// comments` on every line are really bad practice.

Comment: It's a gray area honestly if that much is required, but I do know it's definite overkill and bad practice in the real world. I just don't want to get marked off, especially because the teaching assistants are grading, hah. And the whole `/* Module 0000 */` is also required to go along with my 'structure chart'.

Comment: @Insane, Would it be an alternative to use /* Module 1000 -  Initialize */? That way you can keep the structure number, but also add some information to it.

Comment: @holroy Yeah that'd probably be okay, I had to do a structure chart of the program which uses those numbers so it's not so bad to people with the context.

Answer (score 5):

The first step is to get your compiler to help review your code.  Compiling with warnings…

```
grade.c:1:33: warning: // comments are not allowed in this language [-Wcomment]
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // Required for Visual Studio 2015
                                ^
grade.c:55:26: warning: data argument not used by format string
      [-Wformat-extra-args]
        printf("Name: ", (i + 1)); // Prompt for the students name
               ~~~~~~~~  ^
grade.c:109:17: warning: array index 1 is past the end of the array (which
      contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]
                sGrades[p][1] = 'A'; // Store the grade A into the arra...
                ^          ~
grade.c:14:1: note: array 'sGrades' declared here
char sGrades[NUM_STUDENTS][1]; // Global Array for storing the grades o...
^
grade.c:112:17: warning: array index 1 is past the end of the array (which
      contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]
                sGrades[p][1] = 'B'; // Store the grade B into the arra...
                ^          ~
grade.c:14:1: note: array 'sGrades' declared here
char sGrades[NUM_STUDENTS][1]; // Global Array for storing the grades o...
^
… (etc.)
```

Comment: I don't get _any_ of those warnings when compiling on my university's computer system, and I only get the warning: `data argument not used by format string` in Visual Studio (which I have fixed). Could I ask why this might be?

Comment: Oh. I forgot that you're using a crappy compiler. My condolences. =)

Comment: I updated my comment. I actually don't see any of those except for the 2nd one in Visual Studio, which I fixed. It was a typo; should've been simply `printf("Name: ");`

Comment: I also don't know what `note: array 'sGrades' declared here` or `note: array 'sGrades' declared here` means. And I'm not sure why it's saying I can't use a comment after my first line, that doesn't make sense. Also could you tell me what compiler you used to get these warnings so I can try to fix them? Thank you :)

Comment: I used `clang -Wall -std=c89`, with LLVM 7.0. `gcc` 4.8 is stricter: it treats the `//` comments as errors in C89 mode, but it neglects to point out the problems quoted above. The `sGrades` message is telling you that the last element you can use is `sGrades[p][0]`, not `sGrades[p][1]`.